# Does convergence of $(a_{5n})$ and $(a_{n+1} - a_n)\rightarrow0$ imply convergence of $a_n$

Tags: calculus, limits

As I wrote in the title:

Does convergence of $(a_{5n})$ and the fact that $(a_{n+1} - a_n)\rightarrow0$ imply convergence of $a_n$.

I understand that convergence of $(a_{5n})$ means that $(a_n)$can either be convergent or completely divergent (like $(-1)^n$). I don't know where to go from here though.

I believe that the implication is not true but I can't think of a counter example.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that this was homework and so wrote up a full solution.  These two forms of convergence do imply convergence of the whole sequence.  As a hint, try to show that $a_{5n + k}$ converges for $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and notice that $5n + k$ is a partition of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: that was an excellent hint, thank you very much!